# how to replace text inside the content control

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have attached an image

[image]

In the image, how to use Find/Replace on the content of "<journal-title>Journal of Hazardous Materials,</journal-title>" into "<journal-title>Journal of Hazardous Materials</journal-title>," in content control of "journal-title" ?

Here's the sample word document file [EMI_14381.docx](https://files.fm/u/azv326ku)

Here's the code below

```
Sub SP_jt()

' ' SP_Vol Macro ' '

Application.Run MacroName:="MathTypeCommands.UIEnableDisable.UIUpdate"         
Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlRichText) 
Selection.ParentContentControl.Title = "journal-title" 
Selection.ParentContentControl.Tag = "journal-title"

End Sub
```

Comment: sir, i want replace a text with new text. For example, in above image, the end of "journal-title" content control contains comma(,). How to replace this comma(,) in after the content control of "journal-title" (like "</journal-title>,") throughout the file ?

Comment: I changed the answer now that I understand you want to use Find/Replace. I also edited the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Sir i have tried your concept. but didn't work. I have attached sample docx file above link named "EMI_14381.docx". In this file, see the "References" section in 2nd reference had a "journal-title" content control with comma(,). can u try and fix with coding for more than one content control ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet demonstrates how to address a content control and perform Find/Replace on its Range.

More than one content control in a document can have the same name and/or same tag. Therefore, it's not possible to get a single content control using either of these values as an index. Instead, the Word object model provides the `SelectContentControlsByTitle` and `SelectContentControlsByTag` methods. These return an *array* of content controls so that it's possible to work with all content controls that meet the criterium.

If you want to work only with one (the first one, implying the only one with that title or tag), then use the `.Item(1)` property, as in the example. Once you have the content control you can get its Range and use Find/Replace on the Range.

```
Sub FindReplaceInContentControl()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
    Dim rngCC As Word.Range

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set cc = doc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("journal-title").Item(1)
    Set rngCC = cc.Range
    With rngCC.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = ","
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    End With
End Sub
```